# I setup https, but data still response to client without certificate

Tags: python, ios, ssl, https, tornado

I am developing an iOS app, and I want the data return by my server can only be read by my app.

So, I create self-signed certificate, and setup https in Tornado like this:

```
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(applicaton, ssl_options={
    "certfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "mydomain.crt"),
    "keyfile": os.path.join(data_dir, "mydomain.key"),
})

http_server.listen(443)
```

When after I type the API of my server in chrome/safari, they warned me, but the data still can be read.

The browsers don't have my certificate/key pair, why can they access my server and read the data?

According to public/private theory:

1. the browser have to send its public key, which involved in its certificate
2. if my server trust the certificate by some ways, my server encrypt the response using the browser's public key
3. browser receive the response and decrypt it using itself's private key

In step 2, my server should not trust the browser's certificate! Am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to public/private theory:
>
> 1. the browser have to send its public key, which involved in its certificate
> 2. if my server trust the certificate by some ways, my server encrypt the response using the browser's public key
> 3. browser receive the response and decrypt it using itself's private key

No, that's not how it works.

In SSL/TLS with only server authentication (most HTTPS sites), the server sends its certificate first, the client checks whether it trusts the certificate, the client and server negotiate a shared secret using the server's public key (how it's done depend on the cipher suite), and an encrypted channel is set up, using keys derived from this shared secret.

In SSL/TLS with mutual authentication, an extra steps involves the client sending its certificate to the server and signing something at the end of the handshake, to prove to the server it's indeed the holder of this certificate.

It's only in the second case that the browser has a certificate and a private key, and it's never used for any encryption in any case.

The code you're using here only sets up `certfile` and `keyfile`, which means you've configured your server for a connection where only the server is authenticated. When you're bypassing the browser warning, you're merely telling it to trust the server certificate (since it's self-signed in your case), so the connection can indeed proceed.

If you want to authenticate the client, you'll need to configure the server to request (and require) a client certificate. You'll also need to set up the client certificate (with its private key) in the client (whether it's the browser or your app). This is independent of the server certificate and its private key.

The Tornado documentation seems to indicate the `ssl_options` parameter uses the [`ssl.wrap_socket` options](http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket), so you should look into those if you want to use client certificate authentication (in particular `cert_reqs` and `ca_certs`).

Note that, in general, authenticating an app (as opposed to the user of an app) using a client certificate only works as long as no-one is able to decompile the app. The app will contain the private key one way or another, so someone could get hold of it. This problem is of course even worse if you use the same private key for all the copies of your app.

Comment: I knew it! I knew there must be some parameters to be set, I just can't find them. Thanks a lot.
And about "decompile", I use a password to encrypt my .p12 file. And the password is a string, which exits in the app by binary state. When you say "decompile", you don't mean decode the source code from

Comment: I meant "decompile" quite loosely, in the sense of reverse-engineering the app from its binary distributed form, at least enough to get the private key. Getting the binary portion with the PKCS#12 content and the password next to it would be an example of that.

Comment: When comes to reverse-engineering from binary form, there won't be any security. Fortunately, reverse-engineering is not grasped by majority.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means knowledgeable in this field, but the certificate is only meant to go so far as to help ensure that the server is who it says it is.

Anyone can view the page, if they trust the servers certificate.

To get the functionality you want, you probably want to use some form of authentication, even something basic like a given value in a HTTP header field.

Answer (score 0):

here is a bizarre tip, you just hack your user agent, so tornado will only allow the string you gave, i dont know if iOS browsers offers this, but in Chrome on PC you can override your user agent in 
**developper tool** -> **Settings** -> **Overrides**.

use:

```
self.request.headers["User-Agent"]
```

because it is a string, then you just allow some string to pass:

```
if personnalized_ua not in self.request.headers["User-Agent"]:
    self.redirect("no-way.html")
```

and now, if you want to make access only for iPhone for example, use [user_agents library](https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents)